# Can I restore Google Analytics website profile which has been removed?

Tags: google, google-analytics

I was operating a web site profile using Analytics.
When I changed my site domain, I add new profile and deleted old one.
I want to restore the old one now. No way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you delete it, it's gone.

Comment: Desperated. But what can I do if it's gone. Thanks.

Comment: Nothing you can do except rebuild:
http://www.google.com/support/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1120985

Answer (score 1):

> If  you are an adwords customer, you can be rest assured that your
>   account will get restored in no time. What you have to do is to log
>   into your AdWords account and click on the Analytics email support
>   options. (this is what i had done)
>
> You can also write to: "AdWords Support"
>
> You can also post your problem in the forum
>   http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google+Analytics/thread?tid=1b47f1608b93e735&hl=en
>
> and can also visit:
>   http://www.google.com/support/analytics/bin/request.py?contact_type=contact_policy
>
> However, please note, for the time when the profile remained deleted,
>   you will not see any data in the profiles.

Source: http://www.sourcing2india.com/content/how-recover-deleted-account-google-analytics

Comment: Hi. Link only answers don't make for good answers. If the page linked to moves or is deleted your answer becomes worse than useless. Please **summarise** the relevant part of the page here using the link as a reference.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Google Analytics website profile which has been removed can be restored. I have restored my deleted Google Analytics account.

If you have a Google AdWords account, you should be able to recover it with in 24 hours.

I got this answer after emailing adwords-support@google.com

You can see more details here: http://support.google.com/adwords/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=8206&ctx=go&&contactus=1

> Hello Indramani,
>
> Hope you are doing fine!
>
> I have good news for you regarding your deleted account! I've restored it for you and you should be able to see data in it.
>
> Please check to see if all is fine with the account! Hope I've been of help! Also, I value your feedback. You may receive a satisfaction survey, for this conversation we had, in the next 24 hours--please fill it out. It's a very short survey (we promise!) and your feedback will help us improve our customer service.
>
> Thanks so much for taking it!
>
> Sincerely,
> Padma The Google AdWords Team

Answer (score 1):

You have a month to change your mind. Nowadays, you don't delete Google Analytics accounts, properties, and views. You "move them to the [Trash Can](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6154772)." Then if you don't restore them within 35 days, they are permanently deleted.